# Cannot load Gmail gem in console/app, but can in irb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, gmail

I'm bewildered here. While I can run `require "gmail"` in irb and successfully load the Gmail gem, doing so in my rails console returns `false`. I made sure to include all the directories in `$LOAD_PATH` for irb in the `$LOAD_PATH` for my console, but still cannot get the gem to load in my console.

It may be that the gmail gem is conflicting with another gem that I have installed, but I don't know how to confirm this. It seems other people have had similar problems:

[Why is autoload failing to load files for gems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231134/why-is-autoload-failing-to-load-files-for-gems?lq=1)
[Ruby autoload conflicts between gmail and parse_resource gems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237941/ruby-autoload-conflicts-between-gmail-and-parse-resource-gems/12307739#12307739)
[Rails: Using ruby-gmail gem causes problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020584/rails-using-ruby-gmail-gem-causes-problems/10021623#10021623)

I made sure to include 'gem "gmail"' in my Gemfile and run bundle install. Still no luck!

Stuck here, so would appreciate any help.

Comment: may have just solved the problem. i put 'gem "gmail"' in the top of my gem file (it was previously on the bottom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`false` doesn't mean that the gem is failing to load, it means that the gem is already loaded.

It the rails console could not find the gem you would get a `LoadError`. Here's an example of an app of mine that has `gem 'haml'` in the Gemfile.

```
1.9.2p320 :001 > require 'haml'
 => false 
1.9.2p320 :002 > require 'foo'
LoadError: no such file to load -- foo
```

Another way to see this is to `require 'gmail'` a second time in your irb session.

Answer (score 1):

You must add this line to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'gmail'
```

This is because the gems loaded by your application are restricted to just the ones specified inside the `Gemfile`, and their dependencies (and the dependencies of the dependencies, and so on).

Comment: I made sure that it was in my gemfile. It seems there was an issue with the ordering of the gems in my gemfile (possibly conflicts between gems).